# Alpha material not see through when overlapped

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have a graduated background image set in camera properties and compositing nodes such that the linear gradient is always the same in any view.

I have 4 different materials (shown) with differing transparencies driven by factor. 0, 0.33, 0.66 and 1.0

[image: Blender setup screenshot]

Including Freestyle I have this render result.

[image: Render result]

I would like to achieve this (photoshop mockup) result.

[image: Desired result mockup]

Where am I missing which part of blender out?

Comment: Use Cycles engine instead of Eevee.

Comment: It's for a 30fps animated movie and the render time in cycles is one reason to stay in Evee. Is this simply not possible in Evee then?

Comment: https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering

Comment: People keep hinting I want MORE complex transparency modelling. I want LESS in my example, don't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer was in fact possible in Evee, so ignore the "use Cycles" answers.

Use an emission material with varying strength.
Here I have 0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 0.00 and 1.0 strengths from left to right as you view the planes.

Then use the Compositing in nodes to overlay the rendered image over the background image in the screen mode. This makes has the desired effect of making the 0.00 material transparent to the background but NOT show the objects behind it through the material.

The edges are drawn using the Freestyle tool sets.

[image: Transparency Overlap]